# company-mode no popup graphics at completion-at-point

Tags: company-mode, prog-mode

I tried to install company and lsp on running on Emacs v28.2 on 5.4.240-1-MANJARO for a handful of languages.
Most of the stuff works fine, flycheck, linters,lsp-connection, the popup completion with added documentation. Then i reproduce the config on a other system, but the completion has no more graphic and information in the popup.

[image: working popup and docs]

[image: also in other places the graphics are working properly]

On other systems there is the popup more visual informative:

[image: expected behaviour from official company site]

On both Systems `lsp-describe-session` points out to ruff and jedi.

The installed related packages are quite similare and load via `use-package`
:

- all-the-icons-*
- company
- company-quickhelp
- flycheck
- lsp-jedi
- lsp-mode
- lsp-treemacs
- lsp-ui

can't point out where the problem lays.

EDIT:

The code for downloading company via `use-package`

```el
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(eval-and-compile
  (setq use-package-always-ensure t ; get rid of the :ensure t key
        use-package-expand-minimally t))

(use-package company
  :config
  (global-company-mode t)
  (setq company-idle-delay 0.1)
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)
  ; (setq company-tooltip-align-annotations t)
  (setq company-tooltip-offset-display 'lines)
  (setq company-tooltip-flip-when-above t)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "\C-n") 'company-select-next)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "\C-p") 'company-select-previous)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "\C-d") 'company-show-doc-buffer)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "M-.") 'company-show-location))
```

EDIT II:

Check `list-package` and see that `company` and `company-quickhelp` are still "available" but not "installed" when check it. But when i
check the variable `package-selected-packages` it is in the list.

[image: list-packages]

EDIT III:

updated all the installed packages via `list-package`, still no progress

EDIT IV:

start with a blank emacs and install all with my init.el and config.org new, still no graphics from company.

EDIT V:

Managed to get correct pop-up completion at other ~prog-mode~ buffers then python i
use. the only problem still is the python buffer, where there is no completion at all.

EDIT VI:

I tried to manually do  `M-x company-capf` , and the pop-up-showed up correctly in  `python-mode`. so i think there is an issue with the automatic pop-up. I think the problem lays in the function call in  `python-mode`, which create the popup. Where can i fix this?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to write `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))`. That is equivalent to `"gnu"`.

Comment: @shynur don't know that, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Maybe your Emacs on Manjaro was compiled without SVG support?

Comment: @Dmitry I can open via C-x C-f a generic .svg image, so I assume the support should be given. Also the graphics work in the code (like in image 2) and only don't in the company-pop-up.

Comment: Regarding your second screenshot, are you sure it uses ruff and jedi? The picture shows completions for C or C++. Not Python.

Comment: All in all, you seem to have a bunch of competing packages installed. As a first step, try removing auto-complete, company-jedi, company-lsp, and either company-anaconda or lsp-mode. Anaconda and LSP are different completion systems.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for the suggestion. I removed auto-complete, company-jedi and company-lsp and company-anaconda. Unfortuneately there is no completion pop-up at all anymore in python mode. In other prog-modes there is still completion but still no graphics.

Comment: Also the second screenshot is from the company-mode readme to show my goal for completion for any prog-mode.

Comment: All right. Did you `M-x lsp` before trying completion?

Comment: @Dmitry yes, the lsp servers (ruff and jedi) are connected, but there is no pop-up for completion anymore.

Comment: That's odd. At this point it's probably a good idea to use one of lsp-mode's support channels: either Discord, or Discussions/Issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be a conflict with `tern-mode`. Tern is a stand-alone code-analysis engine for JavaScript. And I used it with its company backend. So i used it with

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/tern/emacs/")
(autoload 'tern-mode "tern.el" nil t)
(autoload 'company-tern "company-tern.el" nil t)
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-tern)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))
```

I realized that when i use `M-x company-diag` and see that the used backend in `python-mode` was also `company-tern`. So i just bind the mode to js2-mode and not to prog-mode-hook and have now correct completion in all languages i try.